# How can I access a variable from another file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So basically i have 2 variables $Score and $Name in file called get.php.I want to compare them with results i get from database. I can't access them. I tried to create a new form but it didn't work. Though I can access them if i put them inside of

```
if (isset($_POST['name_php'])) {
}
```

in getting-data-into-database.php and changing form action to ./php/get.php. But then instead of echoing array items in a html table it echoes results in [browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3K0I.png). Where as results must be in a html table [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nWPt.png).This is get.php file.

```
include("getting-data-into-database.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Leaderboard ORDER BY score DESC";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
$datas = array();

$id = 0;

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
  $datas[] = $row;
  }
  $sliced = array_slice($datas, 0, 10);
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($sliced); $i++) {
    $id = $id + 1;
    echo '<tr><td>' . $id . '</td>' .'<td>' . $sliced[$i]['name'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $sliced[$i]['score'] . '</td></tr>';
  }
}
?>
```

This is getting-data-into-database.php file:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'Leaderboard');

if (isset($_POST['name_php'])) {
  $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name_php']);
  $Score = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['score_php']);

  $adding_data = "INSERT INTO Leaderboard (name, score)
  VALUES ('$Name', '$Score')";

  if ($conn->query($adding_data) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $adding_data . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
}
?>
```

This is html form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="php/getting-data-into-database.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" class="info" id="namePhp_input" name="name_php">
  <input type="hidden" class="info" id="scorePhp_input" name="score_php">
</form>
```

And finally js code:

```
  $("#namePhp_input2").val($("#nameInput").val());
  $("#scorePhp_input2").val($(".Score").html());
  pauseTimer();
  $.post($("#myForm").attr('action'), $("input.info").serializeArray(), function(info) {
    console.log(info);
    $(".Datas").load('./php/get.php');
  });
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using include("getting-data-into-database.php"); ?

Comment: Did you try to use sessions `$_SESSION`?

Comment: No, i haven't tried it.

Comment: `console.log(info);` this is why it prints it to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$_SESSION](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to pass variables from file to file

> get.php

```
// starts a session
session_start(); 

// set sessions
$_SESSION['score'] = $Score;
$_SESSION['name'] = $Name;
```

> compare.php

```
// starts a session
session_start(); 

// compare db value with session
if($_SESSION['score'] == $dbValue){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options.

First:
Create the table inside PHP and send it to the JavaScript File. Use jQuery [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and pass the AJAX POST response to the first parameter of $.html.

Second:
Send the data by json. [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) and [pare it with javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp).

You can also send data from JavaScript to PHP with json using [stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp).